# How can I copy a checked out SVN folder between local machines?

Tags: svn

I have two machines at home (laptop and server) and recently checked out an SVN folder into the laptop - now I would like to make a copy on my server machine in such a way that I could still refresh the folders content from the source on either machine. [The folder in question is around 8 GB so simply checking out a fresh copy to my second machine is not an option]

Comment: You check it out to the second machine (it only needs to be done once). You can then update and commit from either machine, as long as you remember to always do them in that order.

Comment: The initial checkout took over 4 hours plus I don't really feel like paying my data provider for another 8 GB if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as copying the directory from one location to another.

Check out:

```
svn co SVN-URL a
A    a/episodes.py
A    a/episodes1.py
A    a/check-contractors.sh
A    a/list-titles.sh
A    a/get-titles.py
A    a/get-titles.sh
 U   a
Checked out revision 514.
```

Copy from `a` to `b` (however you copy directories, I'm using BSD's `cp` command with "archive" options):

```
~ zyoung$ cp -pPR a b
~ zyoung$ ll b
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   9 zyoung  staff   306 May 15 08:37 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 64 zyoung  staff  2176 May 15 08:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 zyoung  staff   238 May 15 08:37 .svn
-rwxr-xr-x   1 zyoung  staff   112 May 15 08:37 check-contractors.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 zyoung  staff  2053 May 15 08:37 episodes.py
-rwxr-xr-x   1 zyoung  staff  7152 May 15 08:37 episodes1.py
-rwxr-xr-x   1 zyoung  staff  4649 May 15 08:37 get-titles.py
-rwxr-xr-x   1 zyoung  staff  1291 May 15 08:37 get-titles.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 zyoung  staff    80 May 15 08:37 list-titles.sh
```

Modify `b`:

```
~ zyoung$ cd b
b zyoung$ echo "Hello" > new.txt
b zyoung$ svn add new.txt
A         new.txt
b zyoung$ svn ci new.txt -m "Initial revision"
Adding         new.txt
Transmitting file data ...
Committed revision 515.
```

Update `a` to reflect changes:

```
b zyoung$ cd ../a
a zyoung$ svn up
Updating '.':
A    new.txt
Updated to revision 515.
```

Comment: Thank's! - I'm feeling a bit red faced now, was assuming there would be some voodoo being stored outside of the folder structure.

Comment: @norlesh, no problem :) Any source control I can think of (SVN, Mercurial, Git) make the working copy (repositories for the latter 2) portable like this--not tied to a particular place in the file system.